# Pandas merge on column with optional secondary column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two pandas dataframes from two different sources both containing building addresses and I would like to merge them. The issue I am having is that the addresses were not recorded in exactly the same way across the two sets. Specifically with the direction ('N', 'E', 'S', 'W') of the street.

Some addresses in one set have a direction while others do not, so if I use the direction as a merge column some matching addresses do not merge together (e.g. '123 Main St' in one and '123 N Main St' in the other). Some buildings have identical addresses except for the direction (e.g. '456 N Other Ave' and '456 S Other Ave') so I don't want to ignore the direction altogether, but I'd like to use the direction of the street as a secondary merge column that is only used if there is a duplicate address, but ignored otherwise. Is there a way to do this?

The two columns I have for this merge are `full_add` and `dir` which have entries like `'123 Main St'` and `'N'`, respectively.

Here is an example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'full_add': ['123 Main St', '456 Other Ave', '456 Other Ave'],
    'dir': ['N', 'N', 'S'],
    'left_val': [100, 200, 300]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'full_add': ['123 Main St', '456 Other Ave', '456 Other Ave'],
    'dir': [np.nan, 'N', 'S'],
    'right_val': [1000, 2000, 3000]
})

merged = pd.DataFrame({
    'full_add': ['123 Main St', '456 Other Ave', '456 Other Ave'],
    'dir': ['N', 'N', 'S'],
    'left_val': [100, 200, 300],
    'right_val': [1000, 2000, 3000]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to just join on "full_add" then filter out those records that you don't want such as non matching dir's that are not null.

```
df_out = df1.merge(df2, on='full_add')

mask = ((df_out.dir_x.isnull()) | (df_out.dir_y.isnull()) | (df_out.dir_x == df_out.dir_y))

df_out[mask]
```

Output:

```
  dir_x       full_add  left_val dir_y  right_val
0     N    123 Main St       100   NaN       1000
1     N  456 Other Ave       200     N       2000
4     S  456 Other Ave       300     S       3000
```

Comment: Ah, perfect, I was heading in a direction like that, but this is much simpler!

Comment: Glad, I could help. Thank you.